Excercise 2.1.7 in Folland's Real Analysis
This is the question:

Suppose that for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we are given a set $E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $E_\alpha \subset E_\beta$ whenever $\alpha < \beta, \cup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} E_{\alpha}=X,$ and $\cap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} E_\alpha=\varnothing$. Then there is a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \leq \alpha$ on $E_\alpha$ and $f(x) \geq \alpha $ on $E_\alpha^c$ for every $\alpha$

The author also gives a hint to look at $f^{-1}((r,\infty))$ for $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ (this suffices to prove measurability)
My solution is:
Take $f(x)=\inf_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}\{\alpha:x\in E_\alpha\}$. Then this satisfies the inequalities on $E_\alpha$ and $E_\alpha^c$. Moreover, for $\gamma \in \mathbb{R},$ $f^{-1}([\gamma,\infty))=({\cup_{\alpha < \gamma} E_\alpha})^c$=$({\cup_{\alpha_n < \gamma} E_{\alpha_n}})^c \in \mathcal{M}$
where the first union is over the reals less than $\gamma$ and the second union is taken over a sequence of rationals that converges to monotonically to $\gamma$ from below.
I am fairly skeptical of my solution, especially the last part where I pass to the sequence of rationals, because all the solutions I have seen online have insisted on taking the infimum over $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ in the definition of $f$. Is my solution incorrect?
Thank you.

For the empty set, use either $\emptyset$ (\emptyset) or $\varnothing$ (\varnothing).

Your solution is completely correct. There's nothing wrong with passing to the rationals in the way you did since we indeed have
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Bbb R,\  \alpha < \gamma} E_\alpha = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Bbb Q,\  \alpha < \gamma}E_\alpha.
$$
Whether you pass to the rationals at this point or implicitly do so when you define the function is a matter of preference, but your approach seems more intuitive and hence preferable to me.
I would suggest to you that proving that
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Bbb R,\  \alpha < \gamma} E_\alpha \subseteq  \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Bbb Q,\  \alpha < \gamma}E_\alpha
$$
is a quick (but useful) exercise in its own right
